# How to add document(attachment) to Google Calendar using Google Calendar API?

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I want to add document to Google Calendar.
Like we can attach document to Outlook Calendar.

I am using Google Calendar API.

Answer (score 2):

This feature has only just been added to GCal via Labs. I'm not sure if it's available via the API yet: http://broncobytes.boisestate.edu/2009/03/16/attach-a-file-to-a-google-calendar-event/